# How to join tables using sqlite in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, join, database-cursor

I am trying to find out how to do a simple table join on my two tables using a sqlite database in an android application.

Is the simplest way to use CursorJoiner or is there any easier way?

Comment: Better to do this in SQL. Create a [VIEW](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html) with necessary [JOIN](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)s.

Comment: I tried to do that but had problems getting my project to recognize it for some reason.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4957197/334270

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the implementation of [SQLiteDatabase](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java;h=d4f9b2008b83f0131a57800eddf636391c88d492;hb=HEAD) and [SQLiteQueryBuilder](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.java;h=610bf7013e099f303e9ab67d6b4ef899a2bc03c2;hb=HEAD) you will see that it is possible to pass the tables you want to join to the `table` argument of [`query`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) even though the documentation implies it will only take a single name of a table.  The documentation for [SQLiteQueryBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html) is more clear and even suggests things like `foo, bar` or `foo LEFT OUTER JOIN bar ON (foo.id = bar.foo_id)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use a third-party library, I recommend using Active Android

https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid

using it you can merge tables like this

```
From query = new Select()
    .from(Foo.class)
    .innerJoin(Bar.class)
    .on("Foo.Id=Bar.Id");
```

you can even get a cursor back to use in loaders

```
Cursor cursor = Cache.openDatabase().rawQuery(query.toSql(), query.getArguments());
```

more details [here](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/issues/65)