# How do I join two SQLite tables in my Android application?

Tags: android, sqlite

#### Background

I have an Android project that has a database with two tables: `tbl_question` and `tbl_alternative`.

To populate the views with questions and alternatives I am using cursors. There are no problems in getting the data I need until I try to join the two tables.

```
    Tbl_question  
    -------------
    _id  
    question  
    categoryid
```

```
    Tbl_alternative
    ---------------
    _id 
    questionid 
    categoryid 
    alternative
```

I want something like the following:

```
SELECT tbl_question.question, tbl_alternative.alternative where 
categoryid=tbl_alternative.categoryid AND tbl_question._id = 
tbl_alternative.questionid.`
```

This is my attempt:

```
public Cursor getAlternative(long categoryid) {
            String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_Q_ID, KEY_IMAGE, KEY_QUESTION, KEY_ALT, KEY_QID};
             String whereClause = KEY_CATEGORYID + "=" + categoryid +" AND "+ KEY_Q_ID +"="+ KEY_QID;
             Cursor cursor = mDb.query(true, DBTABLE_QUESTION + " INNER JOIN "+ DBTABLE_ALTERNATIVE, columns, whereClause, null, null, null, null, null);
             if (cursor != null) {
                  cursor.moveToFirst();
             }
             return cursor;
```

I find this way to form queries harder than regular SQL, but have gotten the advice to use this way since it is less error prone.

#### Question

How do I join two SQLite tables in my application?

Comment: What error are you getting? Did you try test by replacing the concatenated string with a string literal? (FWIW, I haven't had to use a cursor since 1986 or so. But I don't develop for android.)

Comment: I don't see where/how the inner-join-columns are being specified in the cursor code block. The SQL would be "select desired-cols-list from T1 inner join T2 on T1.questionid =T2.questionid and T1.categoryid = T2.categoryid where T1.categoryid = {the desired category value}"

Comment: THis is my error: ambiguous column name: _id: , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _id, image, question, alternative, questionid FROM tbl_question INNER JOIN tbl_alternative WHERE categoryid=2 AND _id=questionid. So I assume that I need to specify tbl_question._id = tbl_alternative.questionid, but I don't know how to do this in the query-way I use above. And I don't know what to return if I use a "regular" sql-syntax: "Select ' from tbl_question INNER JOIN tbl_alternative ON tbl_question._id = tbl_alternative.questionid AND tbl_question.categoryid = tbl_alternative.categoryid = categoryid;

Comment: @Tim: the way you do it, how do I form the method in the db-helper class? Should I not return a cursor? I am learning as I go, any suggestions that make my code better I am thankful for!

Comment: here I have posted answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567564/sqllitedatabase-query-for-inner-join/55333187#55333187

Answer (score 209, accepted):

You need [rawQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) method.

Example:

```java
private final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM table_a a INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.id=b.other_id WHERE b.property_id=?";

db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, new String[]{String.valueOf(propertyId)});
```

Use ? bindings instead of putting values into raw sql query.

Comment: @necromancer how do you see creating a `VIEW` a better option than `rawQuery`?

Comment: What should be done after the query? How do you know which id belongs to which table, and what if both tables had the same column name for some column? or if there are multiple items for the second table?

Comment: @android-developer "What should be done after the query?" - you get a Cursor, do whatever you want with the data :P; 2. "How do you know which id..." - it's a JOIN, so depending on which [type](http://i.stack.imgur.com/N1IGZ.jpg), you might get ALWAYS, NEVER , or MAYBE populated keys; 3. "...same column name for some column" - can happen, but ambiguity CAN be removed. Honestly I don't know if you can fetch with "Table.column" using getColumnIndex, You can always calculate the index manually, just debug-test it; 4. "multiple items for the second table" also depends on join type.

Comment: assuming the View is a FULL OUTER JOIN of a 1-to-many relation (e.g. [RawContactsEntity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContactsEntity.html)), you can get rows with null KEY on the "many" table, but never on the "1" table so you should branch your cursor pass like so: while (cursor.moveToNext() {
 if (cursor.getValue(getManyTableKeyIndex()) == NULL) {
   /* this is a no-relation row, only has "1" table data */
  } else {
    /* this is a relation HIT, so there's data from both tables */
  }
} 
cursor.close();

Comment: I forgot to add another branching else for "no parent many" rows which you can still get with FULL OUTER JOIN, but usually won't if the relation is strict (I'm not sure if Android enforces relationships). Don't really know how to get ambiguous columns, but you can just test it out on any SQLite CLI by declaring a view with column ambiguity and see what name those columns get on a "SELECT * FROM view_x" query. Then you just apply that to whatever Android helper flavor you want (.query() / .rawQuery()...)

Answer (score 21):

An alternate way is to construct a view which is then queried just like a table.
In many database managers using a view can result in better performance.

```
CREATE VIEW xyz SELECT q.question, a.alternative  
   FROM tbl_question AS q, tbl_alternative AS a
  WHERE q.categoryid = a.categoryid 
    AND q._id = a.questionid;
```

This is from memory so there may be some syntactic issues.
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html

I mention this approach because then you can use SQLiteQueryBuilder with the view as you implied that it was preferred.

Comment: When it comes to RDBMS's like Oracle, views can give you some performance gains but in my experience, they're only used when necessary for performance or reporting purposes. Or to put it another way, you don't create a view for every join query you use. And in SQLite in particular, I don't believe there is any performance gain – according to the answer to this question, SQLite rewrites the query using a subquery. stackoverflow.com/questions/25577407/performance-penalty-for-unused-view#25580319 Android's API might be limiting for what the OP is doing but `rawQuery()` is the right answer.

Answer (score 14):

In addition to @pawelzieba's answer, which definitely is correct, to join two tables, while you can use an `INNER JOIN` like this

```
SELECT * FROM expense INNER JOIN refuel
ON exp_id = expense_id
WHERE refuel_id = 1
```

via raw query like this -

```
String rawQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + RefuelTable.TABLE_NAME + " INNER JOIN " + ExpenseTable.TABLE_NAME
        + " ON " + RefuelTable.EXP_ID + " = " + ExpenseTable.ID
        + " WHERE " + RefuelTable.ID + " = " +  id;
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(
        rawQuery,
        null
);
```

because of SQLite's backward compatible support of the primitive way of querying, we turn that command into this -

```
SELECT *
FROM expense, refuel
WHERE exp_id = expense_id AND refuel_id = 1
```

and hence be able to take advanatage of the SQLiteDatabase.query() helper method

```
Cursor c = db.query(
        RefuelTable.TABLE_NAME + " , " + ExpenseTable.TABLE_NAME,
        Utils.concat(RefuelTable.PROJECTION, ExpenseTable.PROJECTION),
        RefuelTable.EXP_ID + " = " + ExpenseTable.ID + " AND " + RefuelTable.ID + " = " +  id,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
);
```

For a detailed blog post check this 
http://blog.championswimmer.in/2015/12/doing-a-table-join-in-android-without-using-rawquery

Comment: I don't understand where the Utils.concat comes from.

Comment: This is a good approach but will not work if any column name in one table is the same as a column name in another table. Like if both the tables have a column having name ID, then this will throw `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: ambiguous column name`

Answer (score 8):

"Ambiguous column" usually means that the same column name appears in at least two tables; the database engine can't tell which one you want. Use full table names or table aliases to remove the ambiguity.

Here's an example I happened to have in my editor. It's from someone else's problem, but should make sense anyway.

```
select P.* 
from product_has_image P
inner join highest_priority_images H 
        on (H.id_product = P.id_product and H.priority = p.priority)
```

Comment: Yes, I suspected that. But I didn't know how to specify the tables, since the way: DBTABLE_QUESTION.KEY_QUESTION, didn't work. But when I use the rawQuery way it was easy to define which table which column belonged to.