# Doing Inner join in SQl lite

Tags: android

I am working in an android application and I want to work fetch details in my application local Db. The query that I am using has inner join,so its not returning values.But in the same method if I use with the query without inner join it returns value.
Please help me

```
public boolean isAvailableTransitionFile(String MenuName) {

    String query = "select * from Transition_File_Table inner join item_sync on Transition_File_Table.Menuitem_id=item_sync.id where item_sync.itemName=?";
    Cursor cursor = this.db.rawQuery(query,
            new String[] { String.valueOf(MenuName) });
    Log.e("Count", cursor.getCount() + "");
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Arun:First try to execute the query in sqlitemanager.Try to correct the query problem in sqlitemanager and then try to insert the query in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL problems are usually due to a wrong syntax utilization in SQL, always test them before you use them in a program. I found a similar post here:

[How do I join two SQLite tables in my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957009/how-do-i-join-two-sqlite-tables-in-my-android-application)

And you should try this code:

```
String query = "select * from Transition_File_Table TF inner join item_sync IS on
TF.Menuitem_id=IS.id where IS.itemName=?";

Cursor cursor = this.db.rawQuery(query,new String[]{String.valueOf(MenuName)});
```

Answer (score 1):

change your Select Query  as:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM Transition_File_Table 
a INNER JOIN Transition_File_Table b 
ON a.Menuitem_id=b.id WHERE b.itemName=?";
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you, don't use **rawQuery**. U will find useful alternate methods to perform your job. check android's notepad example for a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the query

```
select *
from Transition_File_Table 
inner join item_sync 
    on Transition_File_Table.Menuitem_id=item_sync.id 
where item_sync.itemName=?
```

this joins the rows from Transition_File_Table  to the rows of item_sync where Transition_File_Table's Menuitem_id column matches the id column in the item_sync table.

If the join returns no results this means that n rows can by joined which means that no item_sync  ids have a value that matches a value in the Menuitem_id column of the Transition_File_Table.