# Database query for comparision

Tags: android, database

Hi please anybody please help me with some link that will give details about comparing 2 columns in sqlite table.Actually my requirement is i have to compare 2 columns in 2 different table and i have to retrieve that particular row.Please help me.

Comment: That "particular row" from which of the table?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for resources on performing an INNER JOIN, look here: [How do I join two SQLite tables in my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957009/how-do-i-join-two-sqlite-tables-in-my-android-application)

Please provide more information if this is not correct.  Your question is hard to interpret.