# How to have linked tables in SQLite, C# and Windows 8?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8, windows-runtime

For my Windows Phone app, I used SQL CE with LINQ and I had multiple tables tied together using EntityRef and EntitySet.

These aren't available in the .NET framework for Windows Store Apps so I'm a bit stumped.

It looks like WinRT support for SQLite is a bit basic compared to what I've used when developing the phone app. I can see from Tim Heuer's blog (http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/08/07/updated-how-to-using-sqlite-from-windows-store-apps.aspx) that the SQLite-net library allows me to do things like CreateTable() but there isn't much documentation.

Do I basically have to write code so that if I want to find the item X that is linked to Y then I've (a) got to keep ID numbers in all of the classes and (b) search for the ID number to find the match?

Thanks.

Comment: i think something like that is possible, here is a similar thread dealing with doing it in android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957009/how-do-i-join-two-sqlite-tables-in-my-android-application

Answer (score 0):

[System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) is the ADO.NET adapter for SQLite and it has LINQ support. I would suspect you should be able to use it the same way you were using SQL CE with minimal to no code changes.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to use System.Data.SQLite. However, I'm not entirely convinced that this would work with WinRT but I say that purely on the basis of the fact that the site talks about .Net 2, 3 and 4 but it has become apparent that the WinRT .Net Framework isn't any of those :(. So, in the end, I have decided just to manually link the table entries together by storing the appropriate record IDs and then using Where clauses in SQLite-Net to find the appropriate records.