# Android SQLite using db.query() for JOIN instead of rawquery()

Tags: android, sqlite

I have tableA, tableB, and tableC 
table A and tableB are joined by tableA.Id(PK) = tableB.tableAId(FK)
table B and tableC are joined by tableB.Id(PK) = tableC.tableBId(FK)

I want to be able to do this:

```
SELECT c.ALL from tableC c
INNER JOIN tableB b on c.tableBId = b.Id
INNER JOIN tableA a on b.tableAId = a.Id
WHERE a.Id = 108
```

I have found a lot of posts on the web which uses db.rawquery() to implement this query. However I have also heard that rawquery() is less secure than query(). So for the sake of seeking best practice as a beginner, my question is:

Is there a way to implement this query using db.query() instead of db.rawquery()?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Is there a way to implement this query using db.query() instead of
>   db.rawquery()?

So it's worth to say that rawQuery() makes a trick. But also exists another approach.

query() method is designed for performing queries over one table. **But** the best way how to `JOIN` tables in SQLite is to use [`SQLiteQueryBuilder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html#setTables%28java.lang.String%29) and with setTables() method you are able to join.

Hence i recommend you to use mentioned **SQLiteQueryBuilder**. But it's little more complicated against rawQuery() method where you need to assign only raw statement.

If don't know how to start, check this example:

- [How to use a join with SQLite](http://martin.cubeactive.com/android-creating-a-join-with-sqlite/)

### Note:

Is the fact that `rawQuery()` is less secure than `query()` because `query()` method uses precompiled statements which are safer than "raw" statements. But always you can(should) use **placeholders** which significantly increase safety of statement as main protection against `SQL` injections and statement becomes much more human-readable as well.

Answer (score 21):

This is kind of late, but I thought others who're looking for that might benefit from that:

`db.query()` method natively supports `LEFT OUTER JOIN` AND `INNER JOIN` via its `table` argument so you don't actually need to use `SQLiteQueryBuilder` to accomplish that. Also it's easier and and pretty much straight forward.

This method is widely used in [Google I/O 2015 Schedule app's source code](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/provider/ScheduleDatabase.java#L77).

A Quick example (String constants left out for brevity):

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(NoteContract.Note.TABLE_NAME 
+ " LEFT OUTER JOIN authors ON notes._id=authors.note_id", projection, selection, 
selectionArgs, null, null, "notes._id");
```

The key is in the first argument to `db.query()`.

Currently, only `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` are supported, which is quite sufficient for most apps.

I hope this answer helps others who're looking for this.

Comment: I wish there were more examples.. nonetheless +1 for some updated information. Every tutorial or example out there is using either `rawquery` or `SQLiteQueryBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use query() instead of rawQuery(), given a single assumption - there are no two same column names in the tables you are joining.

If that criteria is fullfilled, then you can use this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34688420/3529903

Answer (score 0):

As per **SharpEdge**'s comment and after trying a more complex example based upon **Nimrod Dayan**'s answer, here's a more complex example.

4 joins are used, a generated column is also used. It uses an expression (subtracts timestamps) and then uses that in the WHERE clause.

**Basically, the method is to append the join clauses to the table name string (SQLite then moves this for you to after the columns).**

`DBConstants.SQL?????` is resolved to the respective SQL e.g. `DBConstants.SQLISNOTNULL` resolves to `IS  NOT  NULL`

`DBConstans.CALCULATED?????` are names for calculated columns.

`DB????TableConstants.????_COL` resolves to column names (`.._FULL` resolves to table.column e.g. to avoid ambiguous _ID columns).

The method (`getToolRules`) is as follows :-

```
public Cursor getToolRules(boolean rulesexist,
                               int minimumruleperiodindays,
                               int minimumbuycount) {

        String columns[] = new String[] {
                "0 " + DBConstants.SQLAS + DBConstants.STD_ID,
                DBProductusageTableConstants.PRODUCTUSAGE_PRODUCTREF_COL,
                DBProductusageTableConstants.PRODUCTUSAGE_AISLEREF_COL,
                DBProductusageTableConstants.PRODUCTUSAGE_COST_COL,
                DBProductusageTableConstants.PRODUCTUSAGE_BUYCOUNT_COL,
                DBProductusageTableConstants.PRODUCTUSAGE_FIRSTBUYDATE_COL,
                DBProductusageTableConstants.PRODUCTUSAGE_LATESTBUYDATE_COL,
                DBProductusageTableConstants.PRODUCTUSAGE_ORDER_COL,
                DBProductusageTableConstants.PRODUCTUSAGE_RULESUGGESTFLAG_COL,
                DBProductusageTableConstants.PRODUCTUSAGE_CHECKLISTFLAG_COL,
                DBProductusageTableConstants.PRODUCTUSAGE_CHECKLISTCOUNT_COL,

                "(" +
                        DBProductusageTableConstants.PRODUCTUSAGE_LATESTBUYDATE_COL +
                        "- " +
                        DBProductusageTableConstants.PRODUCTUSAGE_FIRSTBUYDATE_COL +
                        " / (86400000)" +
                        ") " + DBConstants.SQLAS + DBConstants.CALCULATED_RULEPERIODINDAYS,

                DBProductsTableConstants.PRODUCTS_NAME_COL,

                DBAislesTableConstants.AISLES_NAME_COL,
                DBAislesTableConstants.AISLES_ORDER_COL,
                DBAislesTableConstants.AISLES_SHOPREF_COL,

                DBShopsTableConstants.SHOPS_NAME_COL,
                DBShopsTableConstants.SHOPS_CITY_COL,
                DBShopsTableConstants.SHOPS_ORDER_COL,

                DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_ID_COL_FULL +
                        DBConstants.SQLAS + DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_ALTID_COL,
                DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_AISLEREF_COL,
                DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_PRODUCTREF_COL,
                DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_NAME_COL,
                DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_USES_COL,
                DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_PROMPT_COL,
                DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_ACTON_COL,
                DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_PERIOD_COL,
                DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_MULTIPLIER_COL

        };
        String joinclauses = DBConstants.SQLLEFTJOIN +
                DBProductsTableConstants.PRODUCTS_TABLE +
                DBConstants.SQLON +
                DBProductusageTableConstants.PRODUCTUSAGE_PRODUCTREF_COL + " = " +
                DBProductsTableConstants.PRODUCTS_ID_COL_FULL + " " +

                DBConstants.SQLLEFTJOIN +
                DBAislesTableConstants.AISLES_TABLE +
                DBConstants.SQLON +
                DBProductusageTableConstants.PRODUCTUSAGE_AISLEREF_COL + " = " +
                DBAislesTableConstants.AISLES_ID_COL_FULL +

                DBConstants.SQLLEFTJOIN +
                DBShopsTableConstants.SHOPS_TABLE +
                DBConstants.SQLON +
                DBAislesTableConstants.AISLES_SHOPREF_COL + " = " +
                DBShopsTableConstants.SHOPS_ID_COL_FULL +

                DBConstants.SQLLEFTJOIN +
                DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_TABLE +
                DBConstants.SQLON +
                DBProductusageTableConstants.PRODUCTUSAGE_PRODUCTREF_COL + " =  " +
                DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_PRODUCTREF_COL +
                DBConstants.SQLAND +
                DBProductusageTableConstants.PRODUCTUSAGE_AISLEREF_COL + " = " +
                DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_AISLEREF_COL
                ;
        String ruleexistoption = DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_ID_COL_FULL;
        if (rulesexist) {
            ruleexistoption = ruleexistoption + DBConstants.SQLISNOTNULL;
        } else {
            ruleexistoption = ruleexistoption + DBConstants.SQLISNULL;
        }

        String whereclause = DBProductusageTableConstants.PRODUCTUSAGE_BUYCOUNT_COL +
                " = ?" +
                DBConstants.SQLAND + ruleexistoption +
                DBConstants.SQLAND +
                "(" + DBConstants.CALCULATED_RULEPERIODINDAYS + " / ?) > 0" +
                DBConstants.SQLAND +
                DBProductusageTableConstants.PRODUCTUSAGE_BUYCOUNT_COL + " > ?";

        if (minimumbuycount > 0) {
            --minimumbuycount;
        }
        String[] whereargs = new String[] {
                "0",
                Integer.toString(minimumruleperiodindays),
                Integer.toString(minimumbuycount)
        };
        return db.query(DBProductusageTableConstants.PRODUCTUSAGE_TABLE + joinclauses,
                columns,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);

    }
```

The base SQL, which was created in SQLite Manager, used as a guide to building the method (looks far nicer, IMHO, than the SQL extracted from the cursor in debug) is :-

*Note! `0 AS _ID` is used to enable the cursor to be used by a `CursorAdapter` (i.e. CursorAdapters require a column named _ID)*

```
SELECT 

0 AS _id,
productusage.productusageproductref,
productusage.productusageaisleref,
productusage.productusageorder,
productusage.productusagecost,
productusage.productusagebuycount,
productusage.productusagefirstbuydate,
productusage.productusagelatestbuydate,
productusage.productusagerulesuggestflag,
productusage.productusagechecklistflag,
productusage.productusagechecklistcount,

/*********************************************************************************************************************************
 Calculate the period in days from between the firstbuydate and the latestbuydate 
*********************************************************************************************************************************/
(productusagelatestbuydate - productusagefirstbuydate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) AS periodindays,

products.productname,

aisles.aislename,
aisles.aisleorder,
aisles.aisleshopref,

shops.shopname,
shops.shopcity,
shops.shoporder,

rules._id AS rule_id,
rules.rulename,
rules.ruleuses,
rules.ruleprompt,
rules.ruleacton,
rules.ruleperiod,
rules.rulemultiplier

FROM productusage
LEFT JOIN products ON productusageproductref = products._id
LEFT JOIN aisles ON productusageaisleref = aisles._id
LEFT JOIN shops ON aisles.aisleshopref = shops._id
LEFT JOIN rules ON productusageaisleref = rules.ruleaisleref AND productusageproductref = rules.ruleproductref
WHERE productusagebuycount > 0 AND rules._id IS NULL AND (periodindays / 2)  > 0 AND productusage.productusagebuycount > 0
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public HashMap<String, String> get_update_invoice_getdata(String gen) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HashMap<String, String> wordList;
    wordList = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Cursor cur_1 = ourDataBase
            .rawQuery(
                    "SELECT * FROM  Invoice i JOIN Client c ON i.Client_id=c.Client_id JOIN TAX t ON i.Tax_id=t.Tax_id JOIN Task it ON i.Task_id=it.Task_id WHERE i.Inv_no=?",
                    new String[] { gen });
    int intext = cur_1.getColumnIndex(C_ORG_NAME);
    int intext5 = cur_1.getColumnIndex(TA_NAME);
    int intext6 = cur_1.getColumnIndex(TA_RATE);
    int intext7 = cur_1.getColumnIndex(TA_QTY);
    int intext8 = cur_1.getColumnIndex(TA_TOTAL);

    if (cur_1.moveToFirst()) {

        do {
            wordList.put("Org_name", cur_1.getString(intext));
            wordList.put("client_id", cur_1.getString(2));
            wordList.put("po_number", cur_1.getString(4));
            wordList.put("date", cur_1.getString(3));
            wordList.put("dis_per", cur_1.getString(7));

            wordList.put("item_name", cur_1.getString(intext5));
            wordList.put("item_rate", cur_1.getString(intext6));
            wordList.put("item_cost", cur_1.getString(intext7));
            wordList.put("item_total", cur_1.getString(intext8));

        } while (cur_1.moveToNext());
    }

    return wordList;
}
```

Comment: The OP specifically asked for an example using query instead of rawQuery. Also, provide some text, not just code.