# Retrieve Data from SQLite from cursor with foreign key - android c# xamarin

Tags: c#, android, sqlite

I am trying to run a `SQLite` query with a `Cursor` but I am not sure how to retrieve what I want.

My SQL Tables are below:

```
db.ExecSQL(@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categories(
                            Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                            categoryName TEXT NOT NULL)");

            db.ExecSQL(@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teams(
                            Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                            teamName TEXT NOT NULL,
                            cat INTEGER NOT NULL,
                            favINTEGER NOT NULL,
                            FOREIGN KEY(cat) REFERENCES categories(Id))");
```

The below Is my query that I am trying to run. I need to display the Categories associated with teams, but when I query and display the query, instead of the category that is associated to say "1", the actual number "1" is displayed instead of the word associated to it.

My query is below:

```
    ICursor c = db.Query("teams", new string[] { "Id", "teamName", "cat", "fav"}, "fav= 0", null, null, null, null);
```

Any more code needed, please ask.

Comment: I believe FOREIGN KEY defines a constraint not a relationship, so you need to **JOIN** the tables. In the `query` method you can do this in the table (1st) paramter. So I believe `db.query(teams JOIN categories ON cat = categories.Id, ....etc)` would work. Note I haven't tested this, so there could be typos. More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852348/android-sqlite-using-db-query-for-join-instead-of-rawquery). Oh you will need to include the column(s) you want from the categories.

Comment: I have tested the above, but it still displays the foreign key number instead of the word associated with it...

Comment: So `{"Id", "teamName", "cat", "fav"}`, would likely be `{"teams.Id", "cat", "fav", "categoryname"}`

Comment: I have tried the below and it still shows the number instead of the associated word...

`ICursor c = db.Query("teams JOIN categories ON cat= categories.Id", new string[] { "teams.Id", "teams.teamName", "teams.cat", "teams.fav","categories.Id","categories.categoryName" }, "fav= 0", null, null, null, null);`

Comment: **cat** will always be numeric as it is the value of the reference i.e. the value of categories.Id to which it is linked. As I added you need to include the column(s) you want from the JOINED table (prefixed with the table name to ensure no ambiguity).

Comment: @MikeT I selected the column name `categories.categoryName`, or did i put this in the wrong place?

Comment: Only just realised you are talking C# rather than Java but they appear to be the similar. Are you using offset for column (i.e. should be 5 if so) or column name via something like getColumninfex("categoryName").

Comment: @MikeT Oh i see now, I fixed it just before you commented haha, Thank you so much! Make an answer and I will rate and mark :D

Comment: Great , will add answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOREIGN KEY is used to define a constraint, it doesn't actually define a relationship for the sake of easy retrieval; for that you need to use a JOIN to merge the tables together.

If using rawQuery the SELECT would be along the lines of:-

`SELECT teams.Id, teams.teamName, teams.cat, teams.fav, categories.Id, categories.categoryName FROM teams JOIN categories ON teams.cat = catagories.Id WHERE fav=0)`

However using the Cursor **`query`** (Query for C#) method it's hard to fathom where the **JOIN** should go, it/they can be placed into the **table** (1st) **parameter**.

So :-

`ICursor c = db.Query("teams", new string[] { "Id", "teamName", "cat", "fav"}, "fav= 0", null, null, null, null);`

could become (changed also to retrieve all columns) :-

**`ICursor c = db.Query("teams JOIN categories ON cat= categories.Id", new string[] { "teams.Id AS teamsID", "teams.teamName", "teams.cat", "teams.fav", "categories.Id AS categoriesID", "categories.categoryname"}, "fav= 0", null, null, null, null);`**

- *Note! the use of the AS to use unambiguous names for the Id columns (change to suit but they should be different if you want to use via column name as opposed to column offset) [more on this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46165869/how-do-i-access-individual-id-columns-when-there-are-multiple-id-columns-from)*