# Reapeated columns using setFilterQueryProvider

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a listview with a problem. I want to implement the classic search with the edittext, i am using the **addTextChangedListener** with **TextWatcher()**. The Listview gets the elements from a database so I use cursor and simplecursoradapter so i have to use the **setFilterQueryProvider**. The problem appears when I write something in the edittext, if I write the name of a product it changes all the names of the elements in the list.So i dont know what to do. Appreciate the help.

here is my java code with the listview:

```
public class Lista_general extends ListActivity {

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
ListView list;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lista_general);


     list = getListView();


    EditText edit =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);


    // open database
    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper dbhelper = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(
            getBaseContext());
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();

    // array for SimpleCursorAdapter
        String columns[] = new String[] { "PRODUCTO._id",  
       "nombre","category","CATEGORIAS._id","categoryid" };


    String orderBy = "category";


          // query database

       Cursor c = db.query("PRODUCTO, CATEGORIAS WHERE CATEGORIAS._id = categoryid  ", 
       columns,null,null, null, null, orderBy);


    c.moveToFirst();

    // array for SimpleCursorAdapter
    String from[] = new String[] { "nombre", "category", };
    //String from[] = new String[] { "nombre", "categoria", };

    int to[] = new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.cate, };

    // Adapter
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
            R.layout.productos, c, from, to,
            SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

    setListAdapter(adapter);


    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    //Listener edit text
    edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());  

        }
    });


    adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {

        @Override
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            AdminSQLiteOpenHelper dbhelper = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(
                    getBaseContext());
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();


             Cursor mCursor = null;
              if (constraint == null  || constraint.length () == 0)  {


              mCursor = db.query("PRODUCTO, CATEGORIAS", new String[] { 
                      "PRODUCTO._id", "nombre","CATEGORIAS._id","category"}, 
              null, null, null, null, null);


              }
              else {



               mCursor = db.query(true,"PRODUCTO, CATEGORIAS", new String[] 
                      {"PRODUCTO._id", "nombre", "category","CATEGORIAS._id"}, 
              "nombre" + " like '%" + constraint + "%'", null,                      
                      null, null, null, null);
              }
              if (mCursor != null) {
               mCursor.moveToFirst();
              }



            return mCursor;
        }
    });
}
```

Here is a visual of my error:

first my normal list:
http://i40.tinypic.com/2111k0p.png

after I wrote:
http://i44.tinypic.com/23j04kg.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the queries generated in the `FilterQueryProvider` are not joining the tables properly, so that you end up with every possible combination of `PRODUCTO` and `CATEGORIAS` (which are then filtered by `PRODUCTO.nombre` to give the impression that all the names have changed).

There's also a potential security risk with inserting `constraint` directly into the query, this opens the door to SQL injection attacks. I'm not sure how serious this is in the context of Android apps, but in for example a PHP web application this would allow *anyone* to execute *any* SQL they wished by entering a carefully crafted `constraint`.

---

From the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957009/how-do-i-join-two-sqlite-tables-in-my-android-application) it looks like a `rawQuery()` call is needed in order to use SQL `JOIN` so I would change your queries as follows...

For querying with no filter (i.e. in `onCreate()`; and in `runQuery()` where there is no `constraint`):

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT PRODUCTO._id, nombre, category, CATEGORIAS._id FROM PRODUCTO INNER JOIN CATEGORIAS ON PRODUCTO.categoryid = CATEGORIAS._id", null);
```

For querying *with* a filter:

```
String[] params = { constraint.toString() };
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT PRODUCTO._id, nombre, category, CATEGORIAS._id FROM PRODUCTO INNER JOIN CATEGORIAS ON PRODUCTO.categoryid = CATEGORIAS._id WHERE nombre LIKE ('%' || ? || '%')", params);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @just me this was the answer. Only a little correction String[] params = { (String) constraint }; I am using eclipse and it says that I have to add cast to String.

Comment: Good point, the whole `CharSequence` thing keeps tripping me up. It's safer to use `constraint.toString()` instead of a cast though, I'll edit the answer.