# Converting a value in an sqlite query in android/java

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am having a problem querying a database which has multiple tables.  There are two tables.

Table 1: 
Student ID (primary key)
First Name
Last Name
School ID (an int: this is numbered 1-3 for the 3 schools listed in table 2)

Table 2:
School_ID (primary key)
School Name (a String)

Since there are only 3 entries in table 2 I would like to match the School ID value from table one to output the actual school name listed in table 2.

Here is the section of code I have so far.. when a student ID is entered.. it will return a result such as "24 Smith John 3" I would like the 3 to read Bayside the corresponding value in table 2.

```
    public String getData(String sNumber) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {DataBaseHelper.STUDENT_ID, DataBaseHelper.STUDENT_FIRST_NAME, DataBaseHelper.STUDENT_LAST_NAME,
                        DataBaseHelper.STUDENT_SCHOOL};
    Cursor cursor=db.query(DataBaseHelper.STUDENT_TABLE, columns, DataBaseHelper.STUDENT_ID+" = '"+sNumber+"'", null, null, null, null);
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        int index1=cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.STUDENT_ID);
        int index2=cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.STUDENT_FIRST_NAME);
        int index3=cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.STUDENT_LAST_NAME);
        int index4=cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.STUDENT_SCHOOL);
        String sText = cursor.getString(index1);
        String sFirstName = cursor.getString(index2);
        String sLastName = cursor.getString(index3);
        String sSchool = cursor.getString(index4);
        buffer.append(sText + " " + sLastName + " " +sFirstName+ " " +sSchool+ "\n" );
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**USE INNER JOIN**

```
SELECT t1.idStudent, t1.firstName, t1.lastName, t2.name 
FROM Table1 t1
   INNER JOIN Table2 t2
      ON t2.id = t1.idSchool
WHERE t1.idSchool = ID_T2;
```

**WARNING**

table1 = NAME OF YOUR STUDENT TABLE

table2 = NAME OF YOUR SCHOOL TABLE

idSchool= NAME OF YOUR SCHOOL PRIMARY KEY

**OR**

**YOU CAN USE SOME ORM**

http://satyan.github.io/sugar/

https://github.com/satyan/sugar

http://greendao-orm.com/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9VXIL7gKntc

**I LIKE SUGAR, TRY IT**

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use an ORM, you just need to put a join in your query.

[How do I join two SQLite tables in my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957009/how-do-i-join-two-sqlite-tables-in-my-android-application)

http://androidopentutorials.com/android-sqlite-join-multiple-tables-example/