# How Can we use Join operation in android in sql database?

Tags: android, mysql

I'm using this String to join two tables in SQL. But it is giving me an Exception. Can anyone tell me what the problem is with this?

```
String sql="Select p."+Util.ColId+" , p."+Util.ColCandidate+" , s."+Util.ColAttendanceDate+" , s."+Util.ColAttendanceMonth+" , s."+Util.ColStatus+" , p."+Util.ColClass+" from "+Util.TabName1+" p "+" JOIN "+Util.TabName3+" s "+" ON p."+Util.ColId+" = s."+Util.ColStudentId+" ORDER BY "+Util.ColAttendanceDate+" DESC ,"+Util.ColCandidate;
```

Comment: post the exception details as well here. It could be a syntax error in the string created as the query. What is the final value in your variable str?

Comment: It is not clear from your question which database type you are using. Android uses sqlite internally, not mysql.

Comment: You should post what the String `sql` looks like after resolution if you need help with this. Also, posting the exception would be helpful

Comment: This is my Content Provider that has only 4 basic operations CRUD, Now ow can I join?

Comment: public class MyContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
    MyDBHelper myDBHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {

        myDBHelper=new MyDBHelper(getContext());
        sqLiteDatabase=myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        return false;
    }

Answer (score 0):

please have a look over thease answers here that are cleared how to make `Join` in android.
[join in android 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957009/how-do-i-join-two-sqlite-tables-in-my-android-application)
[join link 2](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-sqlite-join-multiple-tables-example/)
OR 
you can use `DbFlow libs` to come out form these types of problem that realy help us in development enviroment.
see [this.](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/issues/67)
this is very simple as well.