# How do perform joins using Cursors?

Tags: android, sql, join, sqlite, cursor

In my Android app, I use Cursors/ContentValues to do things like fetch results from the Sqlite3 database and then I iterate over the cursor / populate my objects / etc. It's easy enough to perform basic create, retrieve, update, and delete operations.

But what if I want to perform a more complicated query that relies on a join? Do I basically have to pre-write the join query like I do for the create table queries, and then use a Cursor on that somehow? What's the accepted practice here?

Sample join query:

```
SELECT WIDGETS.*
FROM WIDGETS INNER JOIN WIDGET_CATEGORIES 
ON WIDGETS.CATEGORY_ID = WIDGET_CATEGORIES.ID
WHERE WIDGET_CATEGORIES.ACCOUNT_ID=5;
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use `db.rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs)`?

Comment: You write the query using `join`s and all other SQL constructs.  Then you use a query only if you have to.

Comment: @DanielK I had heard using rawQuery was considered bad practice and that I should be using Cursors / ContentValues / etc instead.

Comment: I use The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development as my go to book for Android & he is very, very thorough & he does not mention any downsides to using `db.rawQuery`. Now `ContentValues` come into play when you're inserting data into the database not when you're querying. Anyway, if you can find a reference as to why you shouldn't use `db.rawQuery` I would love to read it. Also you do get a cursor in return when you use `db.rawQuery` so you're still using cursors.

Comment: I can't recall where I heard it, but I'm always open to changing my mind. Is there a reason I should be using rawQuery over a Cursor?

Comment: `db.rawQuery` still returns a cursor. It is pretty much just a different way to build a query.

Comment: Not an explicit reference but see top two answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957009/how-do-i-join-two-sqlite-tables-in-my-android-application

Comment: I see, I was not aware that something like that existed, I am not expert on SQL so I am going to ask @GordonLinoff to comment on whether a view is worth the performance bump. I saw a few of his answer and it looks like he has more experience with SQL.

Comment: I added a sample query to the original post. How would I use rawQuery on this if my table/variable names are all static final fields? For example `private static final TABLE_WIDGETS = "widgets";` The where condition (the 5 in my example) would also be an integer input. If you can post that in an answer I'll accept.

Comment: I want to help you build the query but it may get too big here, can we move it to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114139/discussion-between-aruka-j-and-daniel-k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your sample query & with `WIDGET_CATEGORIES.ACCOUNT_ID` being the only  variable that will change in your query then you can use `rawQuery(SQL statement, selectionArguments)`:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT " + WIDGETS.* + 
" FROM " + TABLE_WIDGETS + " INNER JOIN " + WIDGET_CATEGORIES +
" ON " + WIDGETS.CATEGORY_ID + " = " + WIDGET_CATEGORIES.ID +
" WHERE " + WIDGET_CATEGORIES.ACCOUNT_ID + " = ?;", new String[]{"5"});
```

This will return a `cursor` with the expected `join` information that you're looking for.