# SQLite get list of object that uses composition from 3 tables

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

I have three tables in my sqlite database.

```
Categories: category_id, title
Words: word_id, title, belongs_to(foreign key, category_id)
WordImgs: wordImg_id, title, belongs_to(foreign key, words_id)
```

I'm trying to implement a method List getAllCategories. Each category contains a list of words and each word contains a list of wordimages.

I used this to join the tables but because there are multiple values related to single values I get duplicates.

```
SELECT categories.title, words.title, wordings.title
FROM categories
JOIN words on categories.id = words.belongs_to
JOIN wordImgs words.id = WordImgs.belongs_to
```

Ex. This statement could return

```
Category,Word,wordImg
_______________    
Animal Dog Dog1
Animal Dog Dog2
Animal Cat Cat1
```

How can I navigate my cursor so that I only make 1 of every distinct category and word for my list?

EDIT: Considering using three nested cursors. Haven't seen much of this online, is there a better alternative?

Comment: Check this link out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957009/how-do-i-join-two-sqlite-tables-in-my-android-application

Comment: "Parse" implies that you want to create your own data structure, and to later do things with it. What data structure? What do you need it for?

Comment: @CL. I'm trying to get an ArrayList of categories that I need to pass into my main activity. Maybe parse wasn't the correct term.

Answer (score 0):

try with this query

```
SELECT 
categories.title as categories_title, 
words.title as words_title, 
wordings.title as wordings_title
FROM categories
JOIN words ON categories.id=words.belongs_to
JOIN wordimgs ON words.id=WordImgs.belongs_to
```

You have same column name in all three tables so it would be better if you have alias for each.

If you need to get data from three tables better use JOIN will gives you appropriate data

Comment: I'm not sure what to do after I create the table because I would have to create a list of words for each category first. Have any ideas?

Comment: You will get **array** of data from this query, iterate in `for` loop to show list of words, Is this is what you are looking for?

Comment: I want to make a category from every row in the categories table without duplicate categories. Each category has its list of words which I also need to make from the query.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend you use ORM library instead of writing query by yourself.  I used SugarORM in my android projects, have a look this link http://satyan.github.io/sugar/index.html.

Comment: Please avoid linking to external repositories. Past your code here.