# How to join two tables in sqlite android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Am having a two tables one is travel and another one is call in this two table i have one common field incident id based on that id need to fetch two table value how can i do that.  Now let me explain my problem in detail

Here is my travel table:

```
ID  INCIDENT_ID Lat  Long   Time
--  ----------- ---  ----   -----
1     2         13.2 13.5   13456
```

Here is my Call Table:

```
ID  INCIDENT_ID  DESC   START    END 
--  -----------  ----   -----    ---
1       2         test   23      33
```

Now how to join these two table so far what i have tried is query :

```
  String visitquery = "SELECT   " +  VisitModel.INCIDENT_ID + ","  +  VisitModel.DESC +  " ,"  + VisitModel.Visit_START + " ," + VisitModel.Visit_END  + " , "+ VisitModel.Visit_TRAVELAT  +  " , " +  VisitModel.Visit_TRAVEL_LONG + " FROM " + VisitModel.CALL_TABLE + " LEFT OUTTER JOIN " + VisitModel.Visit_TravelTable
                + " ON " + VisitModel.Visit_IncidentID  + " = " + VisitModel.Visit_TravelIncidentID
                + " WHERE " + VisitModel.Visit_IncidentID + " = " +  id;
```

Am not getting results from travel table how to achieve this is there any other way.

Comment: your field names to JOIN ON match in both tables, so it doesn't know which field from which table do you mean. See the contents of `visitquery`, and you'll understand what I mean.

Comment: @VladMatvienko both have different names

Comment: when in problems like this launch [sqlite3](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sqlite3.html) tool, check your select statement and when done go back to your java coding

Comment: You are wrong. You showed that in the first table it is a `INCIDENT_ID`, and in the second table it is `INCIDENT_ID`. So the field names are the same.

Comment: i just typed it but actually both are different

Comment: did you run `sqlite3` tool? with something like this `select call.*, travel.Lat, travel.Long, travel.Time from call left outer join travel on call.INCIDENT_ID = travel.INCIDENT_ID where call.INCIDENT_ID = 2;` ? what was the output?

Comment: or `select call.*, travel.Lat, travel.Long, travel.Time from call left outer join travel using (INCIDENT_ID) where call.INCIDENT_ID = 2;`

Comment: am not running with sqlte3 tool am just getting call table value not getting travel values

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Here is the [base things about joins](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm)
And here how it can be done in your app with [rawQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4957197/4948172)

Answer (score 0):

What is String value of VisitModel.Visit_IncidentID and VisitModel.Visit_TravelIncidentID ?

Be aware that you have same columns names in both tables. 
Print out this query and check if there is no something like

```
    ...ON INCIDENT_ID = INCIDENT_ID ...
```

Comment: both are different

Comment: Could you post your result of this query?

Comment: am just getting call table values

Comment: can you post visitquery value here?

Comment: ID  INCIDENT_ID  DESC   START    END 
--  -----------  ----   -----    ---
1       2         test   23      33

Comment: same as i posted in question in call table

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

Try with this query if you need all the fields,

```
"SELECT * FROM travel JOIN call ON travel.ID= call.ID"
```

if you need specific columns

```
"SELECT travel.Lat,call.START FROM travel JOIN call ON travel.ID= call.ID"
```

if you need by ID

```
 "SELECT travel.Lat,call.START FROM travel JOIN call ON travel.ID= call.ID WHERE travel.ID='"+id_value+"'";
```

Example

```
 "SELECT travel.Lat,call.START FROM travel JOIN call ON travel.ID= call.ID WHERE travel.ID='12345'";
```

This will work tested.travel and call are two different table names*.

Comment: travel t means how to declare it

Comment: and how to pass that id value

Comment: nithin my doubt is where to pass that id travel.ID and call.ID

Comment: Updated check once.

Comment: It should work,i have tested with this query,its working.otherwise,there might be issue with the ID not matching between 2 tables.